# Saving mail attachments under YYYY\MM\DD folder structure

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to create a mail rule to save attachments from every email that meets certain conditions to a current day folder structure. So far, I only managed to add a prefix so I can at least sort them by the date I received them.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "\\server\folder\"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & objAtt.DisplayName
    Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to extend the folder structure of "saveFolder" to include year/month/date subfolders, eg. \server\folder\2018\01\29.

Any ideas? Thx!

Comment: You need to make sure that the folders you need exist before saving to them. Once there, your current code is quite close to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It should be*

```
saveFolder = "\\server\folder\" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")
```

*[You may also wanna check if Folder exists](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm)*

***EDIT***

*Full Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.mailitem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim SaveFolder As String

    SaveFolder = "C:\Temp\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Month(Date) & "\" & Day(Date)

    ' Check for folder and create if needed
    If Len(Dir("C:\Temp\" & Year(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "C:\Temp\" & Year(Date)
    End If

    If Len(Dir("C:\Temp\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Month(Date), _
                                             vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "C:\Temp\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Month(Date)
    End If

    If Len(Dir("C:\Temp\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Month(Date) & "\" & Day(Date), _
                                                         vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "C:\Temp\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Month(Date) & "\" & Day(Date)
    End If

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & "\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & _
                                                             objAtt.DisplayName
    Next

    Set objAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx @0m3r! Not exactly I was looking for (months & days as sub-folders) but at the end of the day, this works fine too. Btw, how to save email itself to the same location?

Answer (score 0):

Where the folders exist.

```
'saveFolder = "\\server\folder\"
saveFolder = "\\server\folder"
saveFolder = saveFolder & "\" & Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy") & _
    "\" & Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "mm") & _
    "\" & Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "dd")
```